# jQuery plugin: character count for textareas

Tags: jquery

i am using the below plugin for counting the char in the textarea but the only feature i would like to add is that when the character is exceed the limit then it should stop and not allow any more characters to be entered.. so should i just return when it match the allowed character?

below is the sample link with source code.

http://cssglobe.com/lab/charcount/01.html

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.charCount = function(options){

        // default configuration properties
        var defaults = {    
            allowed: 140,       
            warning: 25,
            css: 'counter',
            counterElement: 'span',
            cssWarning: 'warning',
            cssExceeded: 'exceeded',
            counterText: ''
        }; 

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

        function calculate(obj){
            var count = $(obj).val().length;
            var available = options.allowed - count;
            if(available <= options.warning && available >= 0){
                $(obj).next().addClass(options.cssWarning);
            } else {
                $(obj).next().removeClass(options.cssWarning);
            }
            if(available < 0){
                $(obj).next().addClass(options.cssExceeded);
            } else {
                $(obj).next().removeClass(options.cssExceeded);
            }
            $(obj).next().html(options.counterText + available);
        };

        this.each(function() {              
            $(this).after('<'+ options.counterElement +' class="' + options.css + '">'+ options.counterText +'</'+ options.counterElement +'>');
            calculate(this);
            $(this).keyup(function(){calculate(this)});
            $(this).change(function(){calculate(this)});
        });

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: As I recall it is not a good UI decision to prevent text entry. Like on SO here they show negative characters remaining when things get too long. This allows you to correct it without constantly hitting the char limit.

Comment: well the whole reason behind stoping is not to have an extra condition before i save the text into my db, so some users might ignore the warning and hit save and in that case i have to always check to make sure is within the allowed limit before i save that to db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple small changes for this. First, monitor keydown instead of keyup event. This allows you to preventDefault and keep the new text from being added. Next, you have to allow delete and backspace so that they can correct their mistake. There are a lot of corner cases that you should probably account for like cut/paste, arrow keys, etc. That's why I don't like modifying the default behavior for the text area on something like this. You should always do pretransmit and server side double checking anyways so I don't think it gets you a lot other than the potential to annoy your users.

http://jsfiddle.net/qfzkw/2/

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.charCount = function(options) {

        // default configuration properties
        var defaults = {
            allowed: 10,
            warning: 5,
            css: 'counter',
            counterElement: 'span',
            cssWarning: 'warning',
            cssExceeded: 'exceeded',
            counterText: '',
            preventTextEntry: true
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        function calculate(obj, event) {

            var count = $(obj).val().length;
            var available = options.allowed - count;
            if (available <= options.warning && available >= 0) {
                $(obj).next().addClass(options.cssWarning);
            } else {
                $(obj).next().removeClass(options.cssWarning);
            }

            if (available < 0) {
                if (options.preventTextEntry && event.which != 46 && event.which != 8) { event.preventDefault() };
                $(obj).next().addClass(options.cssExceeded);                
            } else {
                $(obj).next().removeClass(options.cssExceeded);
            }
            $(obj).next().html(options.counterText + available);
        };

        this.each(function() {
            $(this).after('<' + options.counterElement + ' class="' + options.css + '">' + options.counterText + '</' + options.counterElement + '>');
            calculate(this);
            $(this).keydown(function(e) {
                calculate(this, e)
            });
            $(this).change(function(e) {
                calculate(this, e)
            });
        });

    };

    $('textarea').charCount();

})(jQuery);​
```